# iPad Text File Importing

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, text-files

I'm trying to import a text file into my iPad application using the method initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:, but when I try to get the filepath to my text file, I am running into some troubles. It seems that my text file is not being found. The following call returns nil (the text file is called legal.txt)

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"legal" 
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
```

Obviously, after this returns nil, my call...

```
NSString *fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath
                                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                            error:@"error"];
```

also returns nil.

I am quite new at this so I might be doing something obviously incorrect, but looked all over SO and elsewhere and couldn't find anyone with the same problem as me.

Comment: Error should be `NSString **`, you are passing `NSString *`. it should write a warning and segfault, its a wonder it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:
by passing the directory as well

Answer (score 0):

Look in your app target's Copy Resources build phase and make sure `legal.txt` is making it into your app bundle. You can also look inside the compiled app package in your build folder (`~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-.../` by default in Xcode 4).